# Please help to translate the Chinese script from this box

Tags: translation

[image]

Received this as a gift from a Chinese delegation who visited our office. Not sure what is it inside this box as still not able to figure it out.... Please translate and help.... Attached pic of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

华拓金服: China extension gold service

中国金融企业最佳合作伙伴: China 's best financial cooperation partners

Translated by google haha

Comment: 华(China) ; 拓= 拓展(expand); 金=金融(financial); 服=服务(service)

Answer (score 0):

华拓金服(hua tuo Financial Services)-best business partner among the Chinese Financial Services companies